# A question about the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{1+a}{p}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be a prime number such that $p\equiv-1\,(\text{mod}\,16)$ and let $a$ be an integer such that $2a^2\equiv 1\,(\text{mod}\,p)$. Is it true that 
$$
\left(\frac{1+a}{p}\right)=1\ ? 
$$
Thanks!

Comment: How high did you check? I verified 31,47,79 and 127. Opinions differ whether including such bits into your question is necessary, but it cannot hurt :-) +1 from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the complex numbers
$$2\cos^2\frac\pi8-1=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$
and so
$$\sqrt2 \cos\frac\pi8=\sqrt{1+\frac1{\sqrt2}}.$$
If we let $\eta=\exp(\pi i/8)$ then
$$\sqrt{1+\frac1{\sqrt2}}=\frac14(\eta^2+\eta^{-2})(\eta+\eta^{-1})
=\frac{\eta^3+\eta+\eta^{-1}+\eta^{-3}}4.$$
Why is this relevant? Let now $\eta$ be a primitive $16$-th root
of unity generating a finite extension $K$ of $\Bbb F_p$. Let
$$b=\frac{\eta^3+\eta+\eta^{-1}+\eta^{-3}}4.$$
Then
$$b^2=1+a$$
where
$$a=\frac{\eta^2+\eta^{-2}}2$$
satisfies $2a^2=1$. We conclude that the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{1+a}p\right)=1$ iff $b\in\Bbb F_p$.

Now $b\in F_{p}$ iff $b^p=b$. But since $p\equiv -1\pmod{16}$
then $\eta^p=\eta^{-1}$, and so
$$b^p=\frac{\eta^{3p}+\eta^{p}+\eta^{-p}+\eta^{-3p}}{4^p}
=\frac{\eta^{-3}+\eta^{-1}+\eta+\eta^3}{4}
=b$$
in $K$. Therefore $\left(\frac{1+a}p\right)=1$.

Comment: Thanks @Lord Shark the Unknown, it is a great answer!